# Am I setting this filter wrong?

Tags: filter

I have a list that I want to filtered only to display items that contain area of midstate and midhudson.

[image]

But for some reason when I add a record and choose the area NORTHEAST or CENTRAL it still displays on this view and it shouldn't.

Here is is the filtering criteria I have set

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you Filter Criteria is wrong. You current filter say

```
IF((Area=="Midstate" AND Area=="Mid Hudson") OR (Comp.Date=="")
```

You should change this to

```
IF((Area=="Midstate" OR Area=="Mid Hudson") AND (Comp.Date=="")
```